# where to define variables for startup events fastapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

In reference to -> https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

items = {}


@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    items["foo"] = {"name": "Fighters"}
    items["bar"] = {"name": "Tenders"}


@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
async def read_items(item_id: str):
    return items[item_id]
```

Why is it better to define a dict at the root level and populate the keys from the startup_event function, instead of making a `global` declaration from within the startup_event function?

Comment: This is opinionated, but you could have several hooks so it would be more dry. Also for bootstrapping purposes it might be better to have one configuration (perhaps even separated into its own file, reading and/or parsing ENV vars could also be a reason).

Comment: couldn't I also make a `global` declaration within the `startup_event` function that would handle all startup configuration and set the proper variables that need to be accessed from outside the function? @HeddevanderHeide